# Store AWS CLI result to bash variable

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, for-loop, jq

I have this command: aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq '.SecurityGroups[]| "(.GroupId)"'

I want the stdout to be stored into a variable in bash.

**Main goal: run a for loop to go over each element stored on this variable.**

So I did this:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq '.SecurityGroups[]| "\(.GroupId)"'))

for val in "${result[@]}"; do
    aws ec2 some command $result
done
```

Looks like bash is interpreting my variable's content as a string because my command inside for is not quiet getting the result properly:

> "sg-01a" "sg-0c2" "sg-4bf"
>
> usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
> To see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help

My assumption is that the result's var should have it's elements stored in this way:

"sg-01a"

"sg-0c2"

"sg-4bf"

But not sure if my assumption is correct.

Comment: You can use the query parameter that's provided by aws cli for your use. So this command will store a list of security group ids in result variable: `result=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --output text --query 'SecurityGroups[*].GroupId')`. To iterate through the list, use: `for val in $result; do echo $val ; done`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes. Add the `-r` flag to the `jq` call to get raw output (which removes the quotes around output) and use `val` in your loop instead of `result`. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[].GroupId')

for val in $result; do
    echo "Run: aws xyz $val"
done
```

PS if you are using VS Code, then I recommend installing and using an extension such as [shellcheck](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=timonwong.shellcheck) to lint your shell script. This is probably available in other environments too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple but robust solution:

```
while read -r val ; do
    echo val="$val"
done < <(aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[] | .GroupId')
```

This will work even if there are spaces within a .GroupId value. Notice also that there is no need for string interpolation.

Comment: Both solutions suits the needs but I'm gonna stick with jarmod one's since with my current skill level ( beginner ) that one looks more readable to me. Thanks guys!